# List has no rows for assignment to SObject: ERROR APEX

Tags: apex, error, administration

im trying to validate a new outbound set into production but still get following error code:

***List has no rows for assignment to SObject***

for this code:

```
    @isTest
    private static void createEEGFile_WithSharing(){
        Account acc = TestDataGenerator.createAccount(true);
    Opportunity opp;
        Profile p = [select id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND ProfileId = :p.Id LIMIT 2];
```

We never changed this apex class. But im trying to validate a new outbound set to salesforce and i keep getting this error code. I want to validate the new outbound set, I get the error message for this apex class, although it has nothing to do with the actual outbound set.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This error msg means that query did not return any results, and you are trying to assign this to SObject. It could be either this line

```
Profile p = [select id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];
```

Or somewhere else in the `TestDataGenerator.createAccount(true)`.

When you are deploying a change set, you can choose to run just a specified test, and then quick deploy the change. This way, salesforce won't validate the change set with other apex test.

Comment: I changed the error line into this : List<profile> p =  [select id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];

Now i got 9 new problems :D 


Any chance you could have a look to my apex class ?